# How to run a custom task(functional tests written in protractor) while the "run" task is up and running?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I am working on a web app that's built atop Play Framework.

The goal I want to achieve is to create a custom sbt task that works like this:

1. start the play application
2. run my custom task (functional tests written in javascript that depends on the running application)
3. stop the application after my custom task is done

Now I am stuck on step two.

I have this sbt script that's working:

```
lazy val anotherTask = taskKey[Unit]("run this first")
lazy val myCustomTask = taskKey[Unit]("try to run shell in sbt")

anotherTask := {
  println("i am the first task")
}

myCustomTask := {
  println("try to run shell")
  import scala.sys.process._
  println("git status" !!)
  println("the shell command worked, yeah!")
}

myCustomTask <<= myCustomTask.dependsOn(anotherTask)
```

But if I try to make `myCustomTask` depend on the `run` task (which starts the play app) by modifying the script like this:

```
myCustomTask <<= myCustomTask.dependsOn(runTask _)
```

I get the following error:

> error: type mismatch;  found   : (sbt.Configuration, String,
>   Seq[String]) => sbt.Def.Initialize[sbt.Task[Unit]]  required:
>   sbt.Scoped.AnyInitTask
>       (which expands to)  sbt.Def.Initialize[sbt.Task[T]] forSome { type T }

How should I solve this problem?

At last, I ended up with a specs2 class like this:

```
  "my app" should {

    "pass the protractor tests" in {
      running(TestServer(9000)) {

        Await.result(WS.url("http://localhost:9000").get, 2 seconds).status === 200
        startProtractor(getProcessIO) === 0
      }
    }

  }


  private def startProtractor(processIO: ProcessIO): Int = {
    Process("protractor", Seq( """functional-test/config/buildspike.conf.js"""))
      .run(processIO)
      .exitValue()
  }

  private def getProcessIO: ProcessIO = {
    new ProcessIO(_ => (),
      stdout => fromInputStream(stdout).getLines().foreach(println),
      _ => ())
  }
```

Comment: Why do you have an underscore after runTask?

Comment: @Christian when i omit the _, sbt complains about not having enough parameters

Comment: I'm no play expert, but maybe you should use run instead of runTask (see the answer below).

Comment: @Christian yes, I tried that, neither of them worked. see the comment below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run is an [Input Task](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Input-Tasks.html), if you want to use it in conjunction with a normal task, you have to convert it to a task first.

You can get a task from an input task by using `toTask` method as it is described [in the documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Input-Tasks.html#Get+a+Task+from+an+InputTask).

```
myCustomTask <<= myCustomTask.dependsOn((run in Compile).toTask(""))
```

Comment: i just tried that, but (run in Compile) seems to be of type InputKey, and toTask method is not defined on it.

Comment: @CuiPengFei are you using sbt in version at least 0.13.2, what's the output of `about`?

Comment: oh, that must be it. i am using 0.13.0   it comes with play 2.1 i think. i will try to use a newer version.

Comment: good, it's working now. when i run myCustomTask, "run" starts. but the problem is that the script in my custom task does not have a chance to run since "run" is not stopping. and my purpose of creating this custom task is to run protractor tests when the play app is up and running.

Comment: I'm getting the same type error, using sbt 0.13.6 and scala 2.10.4

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following to depend on the `run` task:

```
myCustomTask <<= myCustomTask dependsOn run
```

While changing the build I would also use [sbt.Process](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Process.html) API to execute `git status`.

```
"git version".!
```

It's supposed to be working fine(r) with the changes.

Comment: I have tried that, and just tried it again. I got this error: error: type mismatch;
 found   : sbt.InputKey[Unit]
 required: sbt.Scoped.AnyInitTask
    (which expands to)  sbt.Def.Initialize[sbt.Task[T]] forSome { type T }
myCustomTask <<= myCustomTask dependsOn run

Comment: See the answer from @lpiepiora. I've missed that (without having first tested the solution :( )