# Scala Play with Angular and Protractor project setup

Tags: angularjs, scala, playframework-2.0, yeoman, protractor

I'm going to setup a new project with Scala Play on the one and angular/protractor on the other side. I could use sbt-web to load my js assets, but what is with testing?

Is there a best practice to integrate Angular into the Play framework without losing benefits like automated testing by using yeoman? Or is it better to make two projects and use gulp proxy in development?

Comment: After some research I found via a blog post a link to the github page of the guardian. They provide a jasmine plugin for sbt. Next time I'm going to look for further plugins for protractor and cucumber. It seems to me that this is the best solution because tests are still in JS, so the frontend guys didn't need to learn to much new stuff.

https://github.com/guardian/sbt-jasmine-plugin

Comment: You can find a partial answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24280912/how-to-run-a-custom-taskfunctional-tests-written-in-protractor-while-the-run